# Lefthand to righthand bass guitar conversion

Tags: bass-guitar

Can I simply rearrange the strings of this bass to make it right handed, without changing the pickups? Does the position of pickups matter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This bass has an odd setup -- originally a right-handed bass; strings are reversed for left handed, but no strap button for left handed playing; maybe it is at the heel of the neck?

Answer (score 3):

It's not going to make much difference at all. Usually, the pup closest to the bridge can be 'tilted', as the slight difference in nearness to the bridge will make a, well, slight difference to the tone. But as far up the strings as that, hardly any. Particularly on bass. The nut may cause problems, though, as the fatter E string will be trying to pass through the slot made for the thinner G.

Looks like just re-arranging the strings could be bettered by replacements!

Comment: In addition to the nut would you not also have to look at the Bridge setup when swapping all the strings?

Comment: @Folau - When changing strings, it's always prudent to check/change the saddle positions on a bridge as a matter of course. As in the height and intonation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the pickup is NOT the position relative to the length of the string.  It's whether the pole pieces fall under the strings.  When you swap high-for-low, you'll find that the strings STILL go right over the pole pieces.  All good.